# Screen turns black - How to debug?

Tags: nvidia, 17.04, crash, minecraft

Been using Ubuntu for a while. A few months ago I installed Minecraft, and after playing for a while the screen turned black and said "no signal"

Sometimes I can still hear the music playing, sometimes I can't, so I'm not sure whether this is a 'full' crash or just something to do with the video card.

I tried pressing alt+ctrl+f2, to see if it would switch to the console, and it did not. I don't know if that's because it was crashed or because it switched but the screen was still 'broken'

Edit: This appears to be related to Minecraft. It did this crash once while I was just web browsing with chrome and wasn't running much else, but I haven't had that happen again, so I think it was unrelated. /Edit

How would I go about debugging this? Is there an error log, crash log, or some other place I can go searching?

Are there any tricks that might help recover from the crash? (Right now, I'm turning the computer power off and back on to restart)

I've googled for solutions, but since I don't know what's causing this, I couldn't come up with anything useful. I did try some tricks to stop nVidia cards from crashing (including trying to different available drivers) - but nothing seems to have made any impact.

Attempts to fix:

> ```
> I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04.
> ```

I updated Java to Oracle Java 9

> ```
> ~$ java -version
> java version "9.0.1"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
> ```

Changed JVM arguments to give 4G rather than 1G. Arguments are currently:

> ```
> -Xmx4G -Xms4G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
> ```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Minecraft isn't able to run on Java version 9. Installing Java 7, and setting Minecraft to use that seems to have fixed the issue.

I was still getting occasional "screen turns off" crashes happening OUTSIDE of Minecraft, which only started happening after installing minecraft. I have no idea what the cause of those were.

I've done a completely fresh installation of the latest Ubuntu, so I'm hopefully those will have stopped.